# roundcube password plugin not updating

Tags: mysql, dovecot, roundcube

Im trying to configure password plugin for roundcube and cant get it to work!

When i change a password it always pops up a message " An error ocurred, Could not save new password."

My main config file is:

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/database';

 $config['default_host'] = 'localhost';

$config['support_url'] = '';

$config['des_key'] = 'c8191544ce23dfd879c73629';

$config['product_name'] = 'Webmail';

$config['plugins'] = array('password');
```

My password config file is:

```
$config['password_driver'] = 'sql';

$config['password_confirm_current'] = true;

$config['password_minimum_length'] = 8;

$config['password_require_nonalpha'] = false;

$config['password_log'] = false;

$config['password_hosts'] = array('localhost');

$config['password_force_save'] = true;

$config['password_force_new_user'] = true;


// SQL Driver options
// ------------------

$config['password_db_dsn'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/database';

$config['password_query'] = 'UPDATE virtual_users SET password=ENCRYPT(%p, CONCAT(\'$6$\', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))) WHERE id=%u LIMIT 1';
```

Adititional database info:

To add a new user i use the following command:

```
INSERT INTO `mailserver`.`virtual_users`
  (`domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
  ('5', ENCRYPT('newpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))) , 'newemail@domain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself,

edited to:

```
$config['password_query'] = ' UPDATE virtual_users SET password = ENCRYPT(%p, CONCAT(\'$6$\', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))) WHERE email = %u'
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Edit roundcube main `config.inc.php` and add the plugin name 'password' to the plugins array() as shown below, to activate the plugin:

```
$config['plugins'] = array('password');
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/roundcube'
```

change roundcube `plugins/password/config.inc.php` 
Please refer [post here](https://serverfault.com/questions/575389/howto-setup-roundcube-password-plugin-with-sql-driver-and-mysql-encrypt-using-ra)